# NSUserDefault change notification handling in watchAppExtension

Tags: ios, apple-watch, usergroups

I'm creating a  Watch app just to display a value on the watch when the user taps on a table view in the iPhone/host app.

I would like to get a notification the value changes on a shared `UserDefault`. It is shared between WatchKit app and the iOS (host) app, so when the user makes any changes in the host app I'm expecting to get the notification. I've done the following:

When user do some action in application (host app):

```
NSUserDefaults *shared = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.app"];
id object = [self.plantsArray objectAtIndex:[self.plantsTable indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
[shared setObject:object forKey:@"data"];
[shared synchronize];
```

In the Watchkit extension have registered for the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(print) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

but unfortunately I'm not getting any notification, has anyone a solution?

Comment: Have you enabled `App Group` for your app and extension ?

Comment: @iphonic  yes . its enabled for both extension and app

Comment: i am able to get the selected data through the userdefault. But what i need is to perform an action at the time of userdefault change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think iOS has capability of `distributed notifications` between app and extension, notifications will not work between both, instead you need to find a way in which both can monitor changes. For example files.

As you already have created `group`, you can keep a file in the group folder and add a `filewatcher` in extension, update the file from app, and `filewatcher` will catch the change, and your work is done.

For `filewatcher` see code [here](https://github.com/tblank555/iMonitorMyFiles).

Hope it helps.

Cheers.

**Update**

Find `File watcher Swift version` [here](http://github.com/MartinJNash/SwiftFolderMonitor). Thanks `@rivera` for adding.

Comment: Thanks  for your suggestion. But can please tell me how to share file in the group ?

Comment: @ManuRaphy Its simple, you just need to create a file in the group folder, and update it by catching `NSUserDefaultNotification` in the app only, you access group folder by using `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:GROUPKEY].path;`

Comment: Thanks @Rivera for the addition.. I have updated in my answer if some misses it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [MMWormHole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) which provides :

- a channel between the iOS device and the watch which enables you to send data back and forth between them.
- Also provides a way to do Notifications without having to handle the file monitoring by urself.

Using it ,That will be all the code needed to do notifications in ur app

```
[self.wormhole passMessageObject:@{@"buttonNumber" : @(1)} identifier:@"button"];

[self.wormhole listenForMessageWithIdentifier:@"button" 
  listener:^(id messageObject) {
    self.numberLabel.text = [messageObject[@"buttonNumber"] stringValue];
}];
```