# How can I set badge count of iOS app from its today extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8-extension, ios8-today-widget

I'm looking for a way to update the badge count of iOS app icon from its iOS8 today extension. Today extension has a button and by touching that button, user can increase or decrease badge count of iOS app. Can anyone help me with this?

PS: I need to update the badge count without reopening the app even when the app is terminated.

Comment: Not possible directly, though can be done using api, call api, and send Push Notification to app.

Comment: orrr..use NSUserDefaults

Comment: soulshined, how can i set badge count of app icon with NSUserDefaults? can you pls provide me snippet of code?

Comment: @soulshined But wouldn't using NSUSerDefaults still require the app to update the badge count? I can see your idea, update an int in the NSUserDefaults and then when the app is next open, have it check that value and update the app badge count accordingly,

Comment: i need to update the badge count without opening the app.

Comment: No @Dan you share it with an app group ...plenty of tutorials out there ariane26 - just use an embedded framework to share code : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

Comment: @ariane26 You can see one of my answer here, there is a way by adding filewatcher, and update file.. see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27796037/790842

Comment: @iphonic He want to know about Today Extension not watchppExtension..

Comment: @DipenChudasama in all extension sharing of data works in same way.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have created group, you can keep a file in the group folder and add a filewatcher in extension, update the file from app, and filewatcher will catch the change, and your work is done.